# How to get hostname in Solaris machines, through perl script?

Tags: perl, solaris, hostname

I tried this in linux machines

```
my $a =  $ENV{HOSTNAME};
print "\nhostname = $a\n";
```

i get this,

```
hostname = sims5.eng.netapp.com
```

i tried same in Solaris, but i get nothing.

```
hostname =
```

I can use below code,

```
use Sys::Hostname;
$host = hostname;
```

but is there any other way of getting hostname without importing Sys::Hostname in solaris machines.

Thanks.

Comment: what's the aversion to `use Sys::Hostname;` ? Why do you not want to do it that way?

Comment: It's not neccessary to install `Sys::Hostname`  directly from CPAN, if you want your script to work _only_ on Solaris. Check its [source code](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RJBS/perl-5.18.0/ext/Sys-Hostname/Hostname.pm) (it's rather tiny) and choose the method that works on your system. Also, you can just copy the module as is: its only dependency is `Carp`, and it's probably installed in your system.

Comment: no reasons for not using sys::hostname, but my doubt is why ENV{HOSTNAME} is not working in solaries ?

Comment: Because the corresponding environment variable is not set, obviously.

Comment: Based on a quick survey of the servers here, it appears that setting HOSTNAME is specific to Red Hat-derived Linux distributions. Not only Solaris, but also Debian and Ubuntu do not set HOSTNAME by default.

Answer (score 3):

If you reeeally don't want to use modules, you can just read the hostname from the following file:
`/etc/nodename`

Answer (score 1):

This is as @raina77ow suggested using source from `Sys::Hostname`,

```
my $host = hostname() or warn "No hostname";

sub hostname {
  require "sys/syscall.ph";
  require "sys/systeminfo.ph";
  my $host = "\0" x 65; ## preload scalar
  syscall(&SYS_systeminfo, &SI_HOSTNAME, $host, 65) != -1 or return;

  $host =~ tr|\0\r\n||d;
  return $host;
}
```